# Implement graph-like data structure with unique nodes

Tags: data-structures, rust, ownership

I want to implement a mutable directional graph  that ensures that nodes exist at most once.

This is for a board game AI for linking gamestates with each other.

Nodes need to have a mutable part (the `NodeData`) and an immutable part (the `Gamestate`). Gamestates are quite large (~80bytes), so I don't want to store redundant gamestates.

So far, my approach has been using a `HashMap` for the nodes and a `HashSet` for the edges.

```rust
type Node = (Rc<Gamestate>, NodeData);

struct IterativePSearch {
    root: Gamestate,
    nodes: HashMap<Rc<Gamestate>, NodeData>,
    edges: HashSet<Edge>,
}

struct Edge {
    from: Rc<Gamestate>,
    to: Rc<Gamestate>,
}
```

Is this a viable approach? Is it minimal in memory, or is there a more efficient way?

My aim here was to store references to Gamestates in `Edges`, so that I don't have to duplicate the Gamestate. Is this actually happening?

Comment: Hard to say if it's efficient without knowing more about the algorithm. However, this structure makes it somewhat hard to traverse the graph or to figure out if two nodes are connected. I'd consider storing `NodeData` along with outgoing edges, eg. `nodes: HashSet<Rc<Gamestate>, (NodeData, HashSet<Rc<Gamestate>>)>`. That would make `Edge` unnecessary.

Comment: A better approach could be by using interners. The Rust compiler uses this a lot behind the scenes to prevent storing data twice. See https://matklad.github.io/2020/03/22/fast-simple-rust-interner.html and https://crates.io/crates/typed_arena.

Comment: Adding on to my previous comment: You could create a global/thread_local storage for your immutable values.

Comment: I'm not sure if you already know this (and rejected it for obvious reasons I'm not yet seeing), but do note that the usual way to store a digraph is with an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list).

Comment: Thank you for your invaluable suggestions. I'll give them a try!